# RefreshScoped bean creation

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-config

I have configuration class like this with validation on name field.

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties("person")
@RefreshScope
@Validated
public class PersonConfiguration {

    @NotBlank
    public String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

@RestController
class MessageRestController {

    @Autowired
    private PersonConfiguration personConfig;

    @RequestMapping("/message")
    String getMessage() {
        return personConfig.getName();
    }
}

person:
    name: aaaa
```

I was able to successfully start the spring boot application with the above details.
When i change the configuration to this

```
person:
    name:
```

with an empty name field i don't see a binding exception on PersonConfiguration because of the empty name field right away. 
I am seeing the binding exception only when i do a rest call like this localhost:8080/message which is accessing PersonConfiguration. It's like i have to wait till something accesses PersonConfiguration to see binding excpetion.

Is it how it should work?
Is there a way to throw the binding exception instantly when there are git config changes that are not valid, without waiting for something to access configuration

Comment: What if you set it in a local properties file and take off RefreshScope - does it fail on startup then? Without RefreshScope I'd certainly expect it to fail on startup like https://turreta.com/2017/08/08/spring-boot-validate-properties-configurations-when-application-starts-up/